# Is there a way to convert input to predict function into categorical data so it is user-friendly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

The to test my code is: `print(regressor.predict([[1, 0, 0, 90, 100]]))`

This then provides an output. The first 3 elements in the array represent morning, afternoon and evening.

i.e.

```
1, 0 , 0 is morning
0, 1, 0 is afternoon
0, 0, 1 is evening
```

I want the user to be able to input Morning, Afternoon or Evening instead of having to put in something like  `print(regressor.predict([[1, 0, 0, 90, 100]]))`, which means morning, inputvariable1 = 90 and inputvariable2 = 100.

Essentially at the end, when I run my notebook, I want it to ask the user for the following inputs:

```
Period of Day (i.e. Morning, Afternoon, Evening).
InputVariable1
InputVariable2
```

Once they input these, the predict function should be applied and the output should be printed.

Comment: Simply apply if else condition

Answer (score 1):

You can take the input from user then use the stored dict of mapping between the input to list to generate the required list format

```
d = {
"morning": [1, 0, 0],
"afternoon": [0, 1, 0],
"evening": [0, 0, 1]
}

period = input("Enter Period of Day (i.e. Morning, Afternoon, Evening)")
input_var_1 = int(input("Enter input var 1"))
input_var_2 = int(input("Enter input var 2"))

l = [d[period.lower()] + [input_var_1, input_var_2]]

print(model.predict(l))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use if elif and else statements like this.

```
time_of_day = input("Enter morning, afternoon, or evening")
inputVariable1 = input("Enter inputVariable1")
inputVariable2 = input("Enter inputVariable2")

if time_of_day == "morning":
    print(regressor.predict([[1, 0, 0, inputVariable1, inputVariable2]]))
elif time_of_day == "afternoon":
    print(regressor.predict([[0, 1, 0, inputVariable1, inputVariable2]]))
else:
    print(regressor.predict([[0, 0, 1, inputVariable1, inputVariable2]]))
```